# MSMQ degree of reliability

Tags: .net, msmq, soa, reliable-message-delivery

Recently I've had some difficulties setting up msmq communication channel using local account in domain environment. It was pretty common scenario, where I was required to give access to anonymous users in queue properties.

But one thing bothers me from that moment: when my application wasn't able to send messages to remote private queue, they were just gone somewhere. My queue is transactional and I'm setting DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable to true. Outbound message queue was created on machine that sends the message, but after sending attempt there were no waiting messages in outbound queue and there were no exceptions during sending. Is that by design?

Comment: What was the TimeToLive on those messages?

Comment: I didn't alter it, so I suppose it's 4 days by default?